# EpiTwitter Auth Errors

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

So first things first, here's the code:

```
$consumer_key = '*';
$consumer_secret = '*';

$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];

if($oauth_token == ""){
    echo "EFF";
    $url = $twitterObj->getAuthenticateUrl();
    echo "<div style='width:200px;margin-top:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto'>";
    echo "<a href='$url'>Sign In with Twitter</a>";
    echo "</div>";
}else{
    $twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token);
    $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
    $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token,  $token->oauth_token_secret);
    $_SESSION['ot'] = $token->oauth_token;
    $_SESSION['ots'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
    $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get('/account/verify_credentials.json');
    $res = $twitterInfo->response; //valid session
    echo "<strong>".$res['screen_name'] . " is Connected!</strong><br/>";
}
```

It uses the latest EpiTwitter library.  For some reason, every time I try to run the script I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiOAuthUnauthorizedException' in /var/www/twt/EpiOAuth.php:432 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/twt/EpiOAuth.php(404): EpiOAuthException::raise(Object(EpiCurlManager), false) #1 /var/www/twt/EpiOAuth.php(45): EpiOAuthResponse->__get('oauth_token') #2 /var/www/twt/twt.php(18): EpiOAuth->getAuthenticateUrl() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/twt/EpiOAuth.php on line 432

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async/issues/73

I found if i did, the below, the errors went away.

```
try{ 
 $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get('/account/verify_credentials.json');
 $res = $twitterInfo->response; //valid session
} catch(EpiTwitterException $e){
 // this catches all of the EpiTwitter* exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when my consumer_key and consumer_secret were wrong. Or, rather, the values were correct, but the variable names were different because I had pasted:

```
$consumer_key = 'R4kZPHA0xxxxxxxxCtFw';
$consumer_secret = 'blpXdbnxxxxxxxxxxVtuBklFcZ8SA';

$token = '15609xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWL9hH74pEEl0H';
$secret= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxh7IlZ4kMP052Xr0';

$Twitter = new EpiTwitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

...where the variable names were different in the variable assignment lines and the object instantiation line.

But, just double check that the $consumer_key and $consumer_secret values you are using are actually your app's:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/xxxxxxx/show
```

I have tried different Twitter oAuth libraries, and this one looks the most useable. But epicurl does seem to not handle minor syntactic mistakes very gracefully.